# Extracting the column names in R with lapply

Tags: r, ggplot2, lapply

So here is my code

```
h <- lapply(select(winedata, -quality), function(variable){
return(ggplot(aes(x = variable), data = winedata) + 
geom_histogram(bins = 30) + xlab(variable))})
```

There is one problem, and that is xlab(variable) displays the value of the first column as the x axis title, if I choose variable[2] it displays the value of the second column as the x axis title.  How do I get it to put the column names as the x axis title.  names(variable) does not seem to work

Comment: Please review [mcve].

Comment: You could iterate over `names(winedata)` and use `aes_string`, but a better approach is to reshape to long form and use `facet_wrap` to make all the plots in one, e.g. `library(tidyverse); winedata %>% gather(variable, value) %>% ggplot(aes(value)) + geom_histogram() + facet_wrap(~variable)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Map`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

Map(function(var, names){
  return(ggplot(iris, aes(x = var)) + 
           geom_histogram(bins = 30) + xlab(names))},
  select(iris, -Species), names(iris)[1:4])
```

`Map` is essentially `mapply` with `SIMPLIFY=FALSE`, which takes multiple inputs and returns a list.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: This works, thank you. I will look more into the Map function.

Comment: @Mark If you think that this answer is helpful, feel free to accept it so others can see :)